# error "Cannot convert MessageBoxResult to Bool"

Tags: wpf, messagebox

I get the error "Cannot convert MessageBoxResult to Bool"

```
            MessageBox.Show("Insert with Logo?", "Logo", MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel);
            if (MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                imageadd();
            }
            else if
           {
                //No
           }
           else 
           {
                //Cancel
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the return value of `MessageBox.Show` in a variable and compare it to the possible/relevant values of enum `MessageBoxResult`.

```
MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Insert with Logo?", "Logo", MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel);

if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes){
  imageadd();
}
else if (result == MessageBoxResult.No){
  //No
}
else {
 //Cancel
}
```

Fore more information take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms598690.aspx)